# Can you decompose any random parametric curve with Fourier series?

Tags: fourier-series, parametric

Imagine a random parametric curve in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Can the parametric equation always be expressed as a sum of sines and cosines, as a Fourier series? Does anyone know a good introduction to how to do this?

Comment: In math "random" has a very specific meaning, used in probability. It seems unappropriate to say "random curve"

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1378633/every-function-can-be-represented-as-a-fourier-series